# Nothing read after SSL_handshake

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, connection

I try to make a SSL connection, until the SSL_handshake. After the handshake, there is nothing to read from the socket. There is something written to the socket from the client so I expect a response of the server. The socket is connected the whole process, so I don't know what's wrong. The code is displayed under and I have placed comments where the process fails.

```
struct ssl_information {
    int connected;
    int sock;

    BIO *bio_read;
    BIO *bio_write;

    SSL *ssl;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
};

void ssl_connection_init()
{
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
}

void ssl_disconnect(struct ssl_information *ssl)
{
    if(!ssl->connected) return;

    if(ssl->ctx) SSL_CTX_free(ssl->ctx);

    if(ssl->ssl) {
        SSL_shutdown(ssl->ssl);
        SSL_free(ssl->ssl);
    }

    close(ssl->sock);
    ssl->connected = 0;
}

int ssl_read_socket(struct ssl_information *ssl)
{
    int rc;
    unsigned char buffer[4096];

    rc = read(ssl->sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); \\reads nothing on the last call

    if(rc == 0 || rc == -1) return 0;

    BIO_write(ssl->bio_read, buffer, rc);

    return 1;
}

int ssl_write_socket(struct ssl_information *ssl)
{
    int rc;
    unsigned char buffer[4096];

    rc = BIO_read(ssl->bio_write, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    if(write(ssl->sock, buffer, rc) != rc) return 0;

    return 1;
}

int tcp_connection(char *ip, int port)
{
    int flags, rc, sock;
    struct sockaddr_in address;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock == -1) return -1;

    flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL);
    rc = fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    address.sin_port = htons(port);

    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));

    return sock;
}

struct ssl_information ssl_connection(char *ip, int port)
{
    fd_set read_file_descriptor, write_file_descriptor;
    static struct ssl_information ssl;

    ssl.sock = tcp_connection(ip, port);
    if(ssl.sock == -1) {
        ssl.connected = 0;
        return ssl;
    }

    ssl.bio_read = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    ssl.bio_write = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

    ssl.ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_method());
    ssl.ssl = SSL_new(ssl.ctx);

    SSL_set_connect_state(ssl.ssl);
    SSL_set_bio(ssl.ssl, ssl.bio_read, ssl.bio_write);


    while(1) {
        FD_ZERO(&read_file_descriptor);
        FD_ZERO(&write_file_descriptor);

        if(SSL_in_init(ssl.ssl)) SSL_do_handshake(ssl.ssl);

        if(SSL_is_init_finished(ssl.ssl)) break;

        FD_SET(ssl.sock, &read_file_descriptor);

        if(BIO_pending(ssl.bio_write)) FD_SET(ssl.sock, &write_file_descriptor);

        switch(select(FD_SETSIZE, &read_file_descriptor, &write_file_descriptor, 0, 0)) {
            case -1:
            case 0:
                printf("Failed to monitor socket!\n");
                ssl_disconnect(&ssl);
                return ssl;

            default:
                if(FD_ISSET(ssl.sock, &read_file_descriptor)) {
                    if(!ssl_read_socket(&ssl)) {
                        printf("Failed to read from socket!\n");
                        ssl_disconnect(&ssl);
                        return ssl;
                    }
                }
                if(FD_ISSET(ssl.sock, &write_file_descriptor)) {
                    if(!ssl_write_socket(&ssl)) {
                        printf("Failed to write to socket!\n");
                        ssl_disconnect(&ssl);
                        return ssl;
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    ssl.connected = 1;

    return ssl;
}

int main()
{
    struct ssl_information ssl;
    char response[4096];

    ssl = ssl_connection(ip, port);

    if(!ssl.connected) {
        ssl_disconnect(&ssl);
        return 0;
    }

    BIO_write(ssl.bio_write, message, sizeof(message)); //message is of course set to something
    ssl_write_socket(&ssl);

    ssl_read_socket(&ssl); \\returns 0
    BIO_read(ssl.bio_read, response, sizeof(response)); \\ reads nothing
    printf("response: %s\n", response);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: "After the handshake, there is nothing to read from the socket." Does the remote part sends anything? If neither of the two endpoints initiate the conversation, then nothing will happen at the application data step, after the full TLS handshake is finished. It is up to the protocol defining the exchange to specify who speaks first. Sometimes it is the client side (ex: HTTP) and sometimes it is the server side (ex: SMTP, FTP).

Comment: The client speaks first. The function ssl_write_socket is called after the handshake.

Comment: You are using OpenSSL with a non-blocking socket. You are not supposed to call `select()` *before* attempting a read/write operation with OpenSSL first. Don't call `select()` until OpenSSL asks you to, when it returns an `SSL_ERROR_WANT_(READ|WRITE)` error from any read/write operation. In your situation, the handshake operation may have already read the data packets you are waiting for, so they are not on the socket anymore, hence causing `select()` to block. OpenSSL will tell you when you need to wait on the socket, not the other way around, like with traditional socket handling.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but how do I make sure that SSL_is_init_finished returns 1, i.e. that the handshake is fully done?

Comment: @jason For one thing, you don't need `SSL_is_init_finished()` at all. You are ignoring `SSL_do_handshake()`'s return value, which tells you if the handshake is finished or not. You may have to call `SSL_do_handshake()` multiple times, with `select()` in between, to complete the handshake fully. Read the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_do_handshake.html). Also, you are using `BIO_pending()` only for the write `BIO`, but you should use it for the read `BIO` too, as there may be application data in its buffer waiting to be read so don't read from the socket yet.

Comment: @jason this goes back to my earlier comment that you are simply not handling OpenSSL's state machine properly. Don't wait on the socket unless OpenSSL asks you to, and pay attention to all of its return values, as they tell you what is needed to progress the state machine forward if it gets stuck (ie, when you have to go to the socket to read incoming data, or to write outgoing data). And since you are handling the socket I/O yourself instead of letting OpenSSL handle it, you have to pay attention to the socket's return values, too (for instance, you are not handling `write()` correctly).

Comment: if `read()` returns zero it is end of stream, meaning you must close the socket and stop reading. If it returns -1 there was an error which you are ignoring: you should log it with `perror()` or `strerror()`, and unless it was EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK you should also close the socket and stop reading. Don't conflate these two cases.